# Nginx connection refused for some people not others

Tags: networking, nginx

I have nginx serving a bunch of websites on Ubuntu 16.04. A client reported getting connection refused errors but I wasn't seeing them until I tried without my VPN. I checked the firewall (UFW) logs and it's not blocking the connections so they get to nginx and it refuses them but isn't logging the request. I'm able to browse other sites without my VPN and connect to the server on SSH or FTP just not Nginx on port 80 or 443. I'm not using IPv6.

Comment: Increase the log verbosity level (nginx) so that you know what's up.

Comment: Check your DNS records.

Comment: Thanks @DrugsBunny I was going to try that but it appears to have just started working again without me changing anything.